# Jetpack compose Lazy Column exception: View=androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupLayout not attached to window manager

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Sometimes the app crashes with exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupLayout{...} not attached to window manager".
I'm only able to reproduce it with testcase and it happens only sometimes.

My test case: list with 3 items, let's call them A, B, C; and test case has basically 3 steps:

1. Update item A text and remove item B
2. Update item A text and remove item C
3. Try to add item C back to list (and sometimes this causes a crash). (The problem only happens when adding item with the same key back that removed one was)

My hypothesis why it happens:

1. It seems to be happen only when update text A causes to go A text to more lines than it was before. So the recomposition redrew the item A and it will have more height than before
2. If I run fetchSemanticsNode before step3, then it seems it crashes only when item C is still cached (the node exists but it's not displayed)

Seems like these both conditions needs to be true to error to happen. **So I was wondering am I using LazyColumn somehow wrongly or there seems to be bug in Jetpack Compose code?**

Below is the full exception and my code and test case to reproduce it.

- App is crashing with following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupLayout{7744d0c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-62,75 #1020002 android:id/content} not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:544)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerGlobal.java:433)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
at androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupLayoutHelperImpl.updateViewLayout(AndroidPopup.android.kt:776)
at androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupLayout.updatePosition(AndroidPopup.android.kt:659)
at androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupLayout.updateParentBounds$ui_release(AndroidPopup.android.kt:626)
at androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupLayout.updateParentLayoutCoordinates(AndroidPopup.android.kt:581)
at androidx.compose.ui.window.AndroidPopup_androidKt$Popup$7.invoke(AndroidPopup.android.kt:316)
at androidx.compose.ui.window.AndroidPopup_androidKt$Popup$7.invoke(AndroidPopup.android.kt:310)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.OnGloballyPositionedModifierImpl.onGloballyPositioned(OnGloballyPositionedModifier.kt:59)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.dispatchOnPositionedCallbacks$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1149)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OnPositionedDispatcher.dispatchHierarchy(OnPositionedDispatcher.kt:51)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OnPositionedDispatcher.dispatchHierarchy(OnPositionedDispatcher.kt:55)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OnPositionedDispatcher.dispatchHierarchy(OnPositionedDispatcher.kt:55)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OnPositionedDispatcher.dispatchHierarchy(OnPositionedDispatcher.kt:55)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OnPositionedDispatcher.dispatchHierarchy(OnPositionedDispatcher.kt:55)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OnPositionedDispatcher.dispatchHierarchy(OnPositionedDispatcher.kt:55)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OnPositionedDispatcher.dispatchHierarchy(OnPositionedDispatcher.kt:55)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OnPositionedDispatcher.dispatchHierarchy(OnPositionedDispatcher.kt:55)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OnPositionedDispatcher.dispatchHierarchy(OnPositionedDispatcher.kt:55)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OnPositionedDispatcher.dispatch(OnPositionedDispatcher.kt:44)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.dispatchOnPositionedCallbacks(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:348)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.dispatchOnPositionedCallbacks$default(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:344)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.measureAndLayout(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:761)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner.measureAndLayout$default(Owner.kt:196)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:954)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:559)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:565)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4101)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

- UI

```kotlin
const val LAZY_COLUMN_TEST_TAG = "lazy_column_tag"
const val UNDO_TEST_TAG = "undo_tag"
const val ITEM_FIELD_TEST_TAG = "item_field_tag"

@Composable
fun ScreenInitWrapper(viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    viewModel.initModel()
    if (viewModel.isLoaded) {
        Screen()
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen(viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val items = viewModel.items
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        state = scrollState,
        modifier = Modifier.testTag(LAZY_COLUMN_TEST_TAG)
    ) {
        item {
            UndoButton(viewModel)
        }
        items(items = items, key = { item -> "ITEM_${item.id}" }) { item ->
            ItemText(item, viewModel)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun UndoButton(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    IconButton(
        onClick = { viewModel.undo() }, enabled = true,
        modifier = Modifier.testTag(UNDO_TEST_TAG)
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Undo, contentDescription = "undo",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ItemText(item: MyItem, viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    var textFieldValueState by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(text = item.text, selection = item.selection)) }
    val textFieldValue = textFieldValueState.copy(text = item.text, selection = item.selection)

    TextField(
        value = textFieldValue,
        onValueChange = {
            textFieldValueState = it
            if (item.selection != it.selection) {
                item.selection = it.selection
            }
            if (item.text != it.text) {
                item.text = it.text
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .onPreviewKeyEvent {
                if (isBackspaceClickedAndCursorIsBeginningOfLine(it, textFieldValue)) {
                    if (item.id != 1) {
                        viewModel.removeItemAndUpdatePreviousItemText(item)
                    }
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
            .testTag("${ITEM_FIELD_TEST_TAG}_${item.id}"),
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
private fun isBackspaceClickedAndCursorIsBeginningOfLine(it: KeyEvent, textFieldValue: TextFieldValue): Boolean {
    if (it.key == Key.Backspace && it.type == KeyEventType.KeyDown) {
        val currentPosition = textFieldValue.selection.end
        if (currentPosition == 0) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

- ViewModel

```kotlin
data class MyItem (val id: Int, var text: String, var selection: TextRange = TextRange.Zero)

@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var isLoaded: Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    private var _items = emptyList<MyItem>().toMutableStateList()
    var items: List<MyItem> = _items
        private set
    private val undoStack = ArrayDeque<MyItem>()

    fun initModel() {
        if (!isLoaded) {
            // The names matter
            val itemsTemp = listOf(
                MyItem(id = 1, text = "some text long enough for item 1"),
                MyItem(id = 2, text = "item 2"),
                MyItem(id = 3, text = "item 3"),
            ).toMutableList()
            _items.addAll(itemsTemp)
            isLoaded = true
        }
    }

    fun removeItemAndUpdatePreviousItemText(deletedItem: MyItem) {
        // Update previous item text
        val index = items.indexOfFirst { it.id == deletedItem.id }
        val previousItemText = items[index - 1]
        // I was able to get this exception only when the amount of lines of the previous text changed  
        previousItemText.text = previousItemText.text + "Some new text to make it more lines"

        // Undo
        undoStack.addLast(deletedItem)

        // Remove value from list
        val index = items.indexOfFirst { it.id == item.id }
        _items.removeAt(index)
    }

    fun undo() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val deletedItem = undoStack.removeLastOrNull()

        if (deletedItem != null) {
            _items.add(deletedItem)
        }
    }
}
```

- InstrumentedTest

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@LargeTest
@HiltAndroidTest
class UndoRemoveItemInstrumentedTest {
    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val composeRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    undoRemoveItemTest() {
        removeItem(2)
        removeItem(3)

        // First undo causes sometimes failure
        composeRule.onNodeWithTag(UNDO_TEST_TAG).performClick()
        composeRule.onNodeWithTag(UNDO_TEST_TAG).performClick()
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalTestApi::class)
    private fun removeItem(id: Int) {
        composeRule.onNodeWithTag(LAZY_COLUMN_TEST_TAG)
            .performScrollToKey("ITEM_${id}")
        composeRule.onNodeWithTag("${ITEM_FIELD_TEST_TAG}_${id}").performClick()
        composeRule.onNodeWithTag("${ITEM_FIELD_TEST_TAG}_${id}")
            .performTextInputSelection(TextRange(0))
        performBackspaceKeyPress(id)
    }

    private fun performBackspaceKeyPress(itemId: Int) {
        val backspaceDown = android.view.KeyEvent(NativeKeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, NativeKeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
        val backspaceUp = android.view.KeyEvent(NativeKeyEvent.ACTION_UP, NativeKeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)

        composeRule.onNodeWithTag("${ITEM_FIELD_TEST_TAG}_${itemId}").performKeyPress(KeyEvent(backspaceUp))
        composeRule.onNodeWithTag("${ITEM_FIELD_TEST_TAG}_${itemId}").performKeyPress(KeyEvent(backspaceDown))
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that it only happens with compose version 1.2.1, I'm currently not able to reproduce it with version 1.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in compose version 1.3.0. At least I'm not able to reproduce it in this version